# BeanUtills Date conversion Issue

Tags: java, type-conversion

I tried to copy Data(java.util.Date) value from source to target using BeanUtills. It gives a Date to String conversion exception.

what will be the solution for that kind of issue?

My implementation as follows..

```
 import java.util.Date;

 public class Bean1 {

 private Date date;

 public Bean1() {

   }

 public Date getDate() {
   return date;
   }

 public void setDate(Date date) {
   this.date = date;
   }

}
```

===========================================================

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Bean2 {

private Date date;

public Bean2() {

}

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}
```

}

===========================================================

My copy property method as follows

```
    public static void copyProperties(Object src, Object dest) throws   llegalAccessException,InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException {
         Field[] attributes = dest.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
         for (Field property : attributes) {              
           BeanUtils.setProperty(dest, property.getName(), BeanUtils.getProperty(
                src, property.getName()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The latest version of BeanUtils does not support direct copy of Date properties. You'd need to implement a converter (also part of the benutils package) and use that converter with your copy properties method. This is to avoid any errors resulting in any differences in the format of Date properties in two objects. Something like the following would work for you

```
    public static void copyProperties(Object arg0, Object arg1) 
            throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        java.util.Date defaultValue = null;
        Converter converter = new DateConverter(defaultValue);
        BeanUtilsBean beanUtilsBean = BeanUtilsBean.getInstance(); 
        beanUtilsBean.getConvertUtils().register(converter, java.util.Date.class);
        beanUtilsBean.copyProperties(arg0, arg1);
    }
```

I would suggest using the PropertyUtils if you are sure that the Date format in both of your objects will remain the same. You need to use the Converters only if there is a chance that the Date format of Date properties on your src and destination may be different.

Comment: Now i am not getting previous exception...BUT my date Value in Bean1 is Wed May 15 15:46:04 IST 2013. I tried to copy that value to Bean2. I am getting null for date in Bean2.

Comment: As I said, best to use PropertyUtils unless the Date Format is different in these two objects. This is useful when for example, you have date as String in one object and as Date in the other, in this case you can easily apply converters. In your case you don't need to go through this hessel. Anyway, can you post your latest code please, I will see what's wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

The copy could be performed simply using reflection. The `Field` class has `get` and `set` methods that could easily be applied in this scenario.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    Bean1 bean1 = new Bean1();
    bean1.setDate(new Date());

    Bean2 bean2 = new Bean2();
    System.out.println(bean2.getDate());

    copyProperties(bean1, bean2);

    System.out.println(bean2.getDate());    
}

public static void copyProperties(Object src, Object dest) throws SecurityException, NoSuchFieldException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    Field[] attributes = dest.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field property : attributes) {
        boolean isPrivate = false;
        if(!property.isAccessible()){
            property.setAccessible(true);
            isPrivate = true;
        }
        Field srcField = src.getClass().getDeclaredField(property.getName());
        property.set(dest, srcField.get(src));

        if(isPrivate){
            property.setAccessible(false);
        }
    }
}
```